# Rayvista trial: Why I am getting a one row matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, extract, geospatial

I am trying thepackage rayvista in R for the first time using the codes from Milos Popovic tutorial. I have tweeked the location and added some packages since the original codes would not work I am still getting a one row matrix with missing y.

Can someone please help, I would be very grateful. Thanks

```
``
#############################################
# Realistic 3D elevation maps with R
# Milos Popovic 2023/06/01
#############################################

install.packages("devtools")

# install rayvista
devtools::install_github(
    "h-a-graham/rayvista",
    dependencies = T, force = T
)

# install elevatr

devtools::install_github(
    "jhollist/elevatr"
)

install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github(
    "tylermorganwall/rayshader"
)


remotes::install_github(
    "tylermorganwall/rayrender"
)
remotes::install_github(
    "dmurdoch/rgl"
)

# libraries we need
libs <- c(
    "rayvista", "elevatr", "raster",
    "rayshader", "sf", "sp", "giscoR"
)
library(terra)
library(stars) 
# install missing libraries
installed_libs <- libs %in% rownames(installed.packages())
if (any(installed_libs == F)) {
    install.packages(libs[!installed_libs])
}

# load libraries
invisible(lapply(libs, library, character.only = T))

# 1. RAYVISTA - PLACE 18.360219, -71.976729

laselle_lat <- 18.360219
laselle_long <- -71.976729
#
laselle <- rayvista::plot_3d_vista(
    lat = laselle_lat,
    long = laselle_long,
    radius = 3500,
    zscale = 5,
    zoom = .8,
    solid = F,
    elevation_detail = 13,
    overlay_detail = 15,
    theta = 0,
    windowsize = 800
)

# render camera to adjust the scene view

rayshader::render_camera(
    zoom = .7, theta = 0, phi = 30
)

rayshader::render_highquality(
    filename = "laselle_highqual.png",
    preview = T,
    light = T,
    lightdirection = 225,
    lightintensity = 1200,
    lightaltitude = 60,
    interactive = F,
    width = 4000,
    height = 4000
)


Downloading overlay...
 Accessing raster elevation [=========================] 100%
Mosaicing & Projecting
Clipping DEM to bbox
[1] "Dimensions of matrix are: 1x537289"
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'y' in selecting a method for function 'extract': unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extent’ for signature ‘"SpatRaster"’`
```

[image: cropped image of pic la selle]   `

Comment: Just tried your code without installing the packages and it works fine. I tested it in R 4.2.3, rayvista_0.1.7.4.

Comment: Do you mean I need to reinstall Rstudio? I am using currently R-4.1.1

Comment: Nope, you do not need to reinstall Rstudio, you just need to install the newest version of R (4.3.1), check that Rstudio runs this new version, install all the packages and try running your code.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan I have installed R (4.3.1) and It works sporadically now. However,  I am getting a weird map for the Laselle location. Did you get the same, is the data corrupt or my setup still is no good ?